# Change the sidebar to be a navbar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an website with wordpress with theme named starbella-electronics and i want to fix the problem with navbar he is preseted to be a sidebar like on mobile and the menu toogle appear just when you scroll. But i want that menus to be a normal nav bar horizontal.

Here is the site:https://trofez-shop.ro/

Comment: This will need more customization.

Comment: Ok,how do i start or can you help in private message?

Comment: Check how they set up the sidebar nav.